# I need to access document object of document inside an IFRAME. Is there a way to do that for IE7 and IE8?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, cross-browser

I need to get the `scrollHeight` property of the document inside the `<iframe>`. I tried all the options which are:

```
contentWindow.document  
contentDocument  
window.frames
```

All these works fine for IE9,chrome and FF. But i couldnot get it to work in IE7 and IE8.

If anyone has a solution that would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try out :

```
contentWindow.documentElement.document
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    var iframe_doc = "window.document.getElementById('your_iframe_id').document";
    iframe_doc = eval(iframe_doc);
</script>
```

The above code should return you the iframe document, then get the scrollHeight attribute of the iframe document.